# How to run a github workflow with admin permission

Tags: github-actions

I have a github workflow for auto merging PRs that's triggered when PRs that match certain criteria are created, similar to [this one](https://github.com/NexTraq/.github/blob/c8c3e6dc43e2324ecb6aea859136865cb274ee57/workflow-templates/automerge.yml). However, my team's repo has "require merge queue" turned on in the branch protection rule, and the workflow fails at not being able to use regular merge.
I'm hoping to run the workflow as an admin user who can by pass branch protection rules, but I'm not sure how. Can someone help me?